# I am not able to set the value of property after using filter method even after all the conditions are satisfied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
  const eventSeatSelectCallback = (
    
   
    SeatPrice,
    FlightNumber,
    SegmentKey
    
  ) => {
    var postObject = { ...state.post };
      postObject.IsSeatSelected = true;


      postObject.AirPassengerList.filter(
          (x) =>
              x.FlightNumber == FlightNumber.toString() &&
              x.SegmentKey.toString() == SegmentKey.toString() &&
              x.IsSelected == true
      )[0].SeatPrice = SeatPrice;
`
    dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_SEATFORPASSENGER", payLoad: postObject });
  };
```

The line above is giving error in the console as
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'SeatPrice')
I am trying to set the value of AirPassengerList.SeatPrice to SeatPrice

I want to to set the value of Object AirPassengerList.SeatPrice to the value of paramter SeatPrice

Comment: there are clearly no objects in `postObject.AirPassengerList` that satisfy the condition in your `filter` function. You need to handle that case. (I guess by doing nothing.)

Comment: I updated the function parameters.Can u check again

Comment: nothing appears to have changed that's relevant to the point I made. You are filtering a list of objects by a condition, and trying to set a property on the first one of those. It is always logically possible that there are no objects satisfying the condition - you need to deal with that case in a way that won't crash your code.

Comment: It cannot find the property values inside the x object of filter function .All the conditions are satisfied every time

Answer (score 0):

May be you can update the element by index

```
  const eventSeatSelectCallback = (
    SeatPrice,
    FlightNumber,
    SegmentKey
    
  ) => {

      var postObject = { ...state.post };

      postObject.IsSeatSelected = true;

      const passengerIndex = postObject.AirPassengerList?.findIndex(
          (x) =>
              x.FlightNumber == FlightNumber.toString() &&
              x.SegmentKey.toString() == SegmentKey.toString() &&
              x.IsSelected == true
      );
 
      // update if item is found
      if (passengerIndex !== -1) {
         postObject.AirPassengerList[passengerIndex].SeatPrice = SeatPrice;
         // do you need to updated this only after price update
         // dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_SEATFORPASSENGER", payLoad: postObject });
      }   

      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_SEATFORPASSENGER", payLoad: postObject });  

  };
```

Hope it helps